# Does Swagger UI supports @ModelAttribute?

Tags: swagger-ui

I have configured Swagger for REST web services, it works well and fetches my Request, Response parameters with clean documentation but it fails to display the Model Schema when using `@ModelAttribute` annotation

Is it something that I have to do to make Swagger accept such annotation as it is with `@RequestBody`?

Comment: There are different implementations of swagger-ui. It would be useful to mention the library used: springdoc-openapi, springfox

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem in using  `@ModelAttribute` on a method parameter and it turned out that the object was not a proper POJO and could not be serialized.  My first step to figuring this out was to enable trace level logging of the Swagger/Spring classes with the following XML block added to my log4j2.xml:

```
<Logger name="com.mangofactory" level="trace"></Logger>
```

This caused the following logged events to be output:

```
13:15:43.954 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.mangofactory.swagger.readers.operation.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander - Expanding parameter type: class org.joda.time.DateTime
13:15:43.955 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.mangofactory.swagger.readers.operation.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander - Attempting to expanding field: private static final long org.joda.time.DateTime.serialVersionUID
13:15:43.956 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.mangofactory.swagger.readers.operation.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander - Skipping expansion of field: private static final long org.joda.time.DateTime.serialVersionUID, not a valid bean property
```

Depending on your object and its needs, you may need to define a mapping using the SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin.directModelSubstitute or make sure your object has matching getters/setters.  Another option is to use the Jackson Data Binding library.